# Element <input> is not reachable by keyboard - InputField under ShadwoRoot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dom, input, sendkeys

I use newest Chrome and chromedriver. 
I have a website with DOM elements and i will type any text in an inputfield 
**HTML Code**  (sorry for screenshot)
[image]

**Python Code:** 
#Expand Shadow 
def expand_shadow_element(element): 
shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot.children', element) 
return shadow_root 
... 
root1 = driver.find_element_by_id("UI-tf_Vorgangsname") 
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
root2 = shadow_root1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aLjh.png).find_element_by_xpath("//input[@part='value']")
time.sleep(2)
root2.click()
time.sleep(2)
root2.send_keys('testssdfs')

**I become this messages:**  
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard

I see, click is working, cursor is aktiv in Input Field, but send_keys doesn't work. 
[image]
Do you have any idea? 
Many Thanks!

Comment: I dont know, why are answers disabled. I need answers :)

Comment: I'm asking about your previous questions. When we see people who asking questions, getting perfect answers but not even accepting them we ask ourselves do we really want to help such persons.

Comment: Done, sorry but i'am rookie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. 
Sendkeys doesn't work, but i found a hybrid solution.
I use this Python script without send_keys, and i use robotframework kernsystem.
xy.robot file
...
${Element}=  **Get Element ID Input**   UI-tf_Vorgnagsname
Press Keys   ${Element}   Test text
...
So i can write in this input field.